# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**
I don't have multiple jar libraries in my lib folder.
I have tried multiDexEnabled true.
I have changed the targeted version of the sdk.
I have cleaned the project several times.

But it shows me error again and again

What should i do ??**

Comment: remove `multiDexEnabled true` and try

Comment: Give us the total stack of errors.

Comment: Seems you have some compatibility issues with some dependency libs.
Could you send the stacktrace?

Comment: i have removed multiDexEnabled. But still i gives me that error

Comment: it is showing me the error when i run the project.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

@CiroRizzo

Comment: anybody can suggest me what should i do now ??

Comment: I have figured out this error.

Answer (score 0):

try to add "multiDexEnabled = true" in file build.gradle

`android {
    *
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled = true
}`

Comment: This is my bulde.gradle default configuration part
  



defaultConfig   {
       
 applicationId "purepushar.flashlight.torchlight.lamp.strobelight"

        minSdkVersion 9

        targetSdkVersion 19
        
         multiDexEnabled = true
    }

Comment: After a day the problem is solved.

Error was solved
After changing the path of the jdk from 1.8.0 to 1.7.0.

My computer OS is 32-bit and i was using jdk of 64 bit.